# Image change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following on from another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861645/change-image-on-scroll)

This script changes an image on page scroll. However this script would be excessively large if it was for example, used for frames of a video with 200+ images. Is it possible to shorten this script for use with large number of files?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

Minor code tweaks...

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/ygkWH/6/

### HTML

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /><b>Frame: 0</b>
```

### [illustrative] CSS

```
img, b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
body {
    height: 10000px;
}
```

### JQuery

```
// Array of images to swap between
var images = [];

// Add 200 items to array
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    images.push('http://placekitten.com/' + (100 + i) + '/' + (100 + i));
}

var totalImages = images.length;

var pageHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

// Work out how often we should change image (i.e. how far we scroll between changes)
var scrollInterval = Math.floor(pageHeight / totalImages);

$(document).scroll(function () {
    // Which one should we show at this scroll point?
    i = Math.floor($(this).scrollTop() / scrollInterval);
    // Show the corresponding image from the array
    $('img').attr('src', images[i]);
    $('b').text('Frame: ' + i);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to preload the images, say 10 images before it is due to show?